# I run this code "vagrant up" in Terminal and I get an error of 'No such file or directory' - how to fix this?

Tags: macos, installation, homestead

I'm trying to install Homestead on my terminal. I was in my home directory and ran the code "vagrant up" but I get an error. This was what I typed in:

```
MACs-MBP:Homestead MAC$ vagrant up
```

And this was the error:

```
/Users/MAC/web/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:118:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/MAC/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/MAC/web/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:338:in `provision'
from /Users/MAC/web/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:115:in `block in configure'
from /Users/MAC/web/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:114:in `each'
from /Users/MAC/web/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:114:in `configure'
from /Users/MAC/web/Homestead/Vagrantfile:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/bin/vagrant:130:in `ensure in <main>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/bin/vagrant:130:in `<main>'
```

How would I fix this? I am really confused. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line in your error message indicates that you need to generate an SSH key first.

In your terminal (but outside Homestead interface), type:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

When it asks for the directory to save your key, press Enter for default directory, which is where your Homestead is searching. When it asks for a passphrase, it's good to have one.

Then try `vagrant up` again.

Comment: I eventually resolved this yesterday, and you're right it's because I didn't generate a key. Thanks for the response, I'll vote yours as best answer since it was correct